How does registration work in a modern accordion?
Please explain some of the basics of registration of the accordion.
Why does an accordion sometimes sound like an organ, sometimes like a flute?

I never heard an accordion sound like a flute. There may be accordions with registers called "flute", but that doesn't mean it will actually sound like a flute. Organ registers also have often quite misleading names.

@leftaroundabout I agree, how-ever, the colloquial names of the "pipes" or "reeds" are common. also the other poster talks about "flute-like" sound for the cassotto. I am no acoustician, but I learned that much of the sound characteristics of instruments comes from the "attack" phase - this and the actual sound of flowing air are definitly making a difference for flute. The sound itself might then be quite similar due to less overtones.

For example: https://youtu.be/OdoCHKfW22s?t=26

Accordions can sometimes sound like an organ. This comes from the so-called registration:
The basic principle of sound creation is similar to single-reed instruments like clarinet or saxophone. However, in the accordion, the reeds are made from steel and they vibrate freely through producing over- and under-pressure in a tone chamber at the frequency of the desired tone (the weight and size of the reed determines the pitch/frequency). See the description of free reed aerophones in Wikipedia.
The accordion has no real resonant body (at least not as with guitars, violins or pianos).
Regarding the registers let's start with the popular, French musette-style sound: this comes from two sets of reeds that are slightly detuned by 2-3 Hz or so. This makes what is called a tremolo sound. In older instruments one can even find 3 sets, tuned 3Hz below, at pitch, and 3Hz above at the same time. It became popular because one couldn't identify slight mistunings under such "cirumstances".
From here we turn to the similarities to the organ (see Wikipedia's description of reed pipes). Modern accordions have additional sets of reeds to extend the range and also to add different sound characteristics. Hence the "normal" register is called 8' ("einchörig" in German), and there are 16' ("octava") and 4' ("piccolo"). With these options and some mechanics one can create a number of sounds just as in church organs. For example a combination 4'+16' played 8va (and in a church) really sounds like an organ. On the other hand, a hard fp (forte-piano - do that with an organ) chord in 4+8+16 can sound like a brass section of a big band.
See here for notation:

For more mellow tones, instrument makers invented the cassotto, which is produced by having the reeds arranged differently (turned by 90 degrees and having a kind of small rectangular box around them - hence the name) in the body. This is then normally applied to the 8 and 16 foot sets and is fixed.
All this applies to the right-hand-side or "discant". The left-hand-side ("bass") works similarly in regards to sound creation, but registration and especially the distinction between the folkish- oom-paa-paa basses and the so called free-bass / single-tone manual are worth a dedicated article.
By the way - the number of reeds then makes the accordion quite expensive:
Counting: 4 or 5 sets of reeds x 41 keys x 2 (distinct reeds for pushing and drawing the bellows) makes ~350-400 individual reeds that are manually fitted and tuned.
An excellent introduction to how an accordion can be used (for composers) and sounds is here (registration is introduced at 5:16, however he omits register combinations and "tremolo"):

The "einchörig" register on an accordion is usually called "clarinet" in English, and "octava" is called "bassoon".
